# NVRAM Variable syntax

Tags: linux, router, firmware, asuswrt-merlin, nvram

I'm trying to edit the `client_customlist` variable in my router with Merlin firmware, and am a bit confused with the syntax; when I export it and then look at it, most of them end with 3 `>`, like this:

`<S|GHome>E4:99:42:99:A6:99>0>23>>>>`

but there are a couple that end with only 1, like this:

`<S|OL (WL)>00:99:69:02:99:FD>0>22>>`

Does anyone know why this is? I'm not coming up with anything doing some Google-Fu.

Comment: Hi, SO is programming questions site. This probably better fits to SuperUser or ServerFault where general and professsional server/networking sw/hw is discussed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whelp, I never got an answer as to the "why", so I gambled with a mass replace of:

`>>>><`

to

`>><`

imported the new value back to the variable, tested it all out, and it worked fine. If anyone knows "why" it was adding extra `>` to some of them, I'd still love to know.